# The set of functions 1, $\cos x$, $\sin x$, $\dots,$ $\cos nx$, $\sin nx$, $\dots$ is orthogonal in $\mathscr{C}[-\pi, \pi]$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem in the title of this question is Example 5 of 1.3 in Edwards's Multivariable Calculus. What I want to know is the anti-derivative of $\cos x \cos nx$, if I know which then I solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Use addition thoerems for sine and cosine.